# How to keep duplicate repository in sync with github?

Tags: git, clone, github

I have used github duplicate option with --bare in clone and uploaded to a different account in github.com

Used as in this [link](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/duplicating-a-repository#mirroring-a-repository)

Just as a process to handover the project to another team.

But there are recent changes in the original repository, how to sync those changes there, all branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is clone as bare repository and fetch the changes from original repo whenever there are changes.

```
git clone --mirror https://primary_repo_url/primary_repo.git
git fetch origin
```

Then, add the other new repo as another remote and push it to that repo whenever there is changes to sync.

```
cd primary_repo.git
git remote add --mirror=fetch secondary https://secondary_repo_url/secondary_repo.git

git push secondary --all
```

For more details and other options, I followed this [link](https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/git/177/git-sync-repos.html#:%7E:text=The%20secondary%20repo%20will%20now%20have%20all%20the,origin%20%23%20git%20push%20secondary%20--all%20Reverse%20Sync)